# Simplify $(-i)^\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I simplify $(-i)^\frac{1}{4}$?
I know that it has norm 1 and I think that the angle is $-\frac{\pi}{4}$,
but I'm not really sure.

Comment: It would be nice if you would start by telling us what does $(-i)^{1/4}$ *mean*.

Comment: Set $z=(-i)^{1/4}$ and use $z^4=-i$ to get a polynomial you can solve.

Comment: Consider polar representation

Comment: There are a few possible angles, none of which is $-\frac\pi4$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$-i=e^{3i\pi/2+2k\pi}$$

for all integers $k$.

Now take the 4th root...

$$(-i)^{1/4}=e^{3i\pi/8+k\pi/2}=\cos{\left(\frac{3\pi}{8}+\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}+i\sin{\left(\frac{3\pi}{8}+\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}$$

If you want your expression in rectangular coordinates (since that is how you started), you could expand sine and cosine using the addition formulas and the half angle identities as

$$\frac{3\pi}{8}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

It will be a little messier but you'd have another form of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Does this figure help you (a plot in the complex plane), where the red arrow points to $-i$?  The identity ($1$) is to the right and each multiplication rotates the identity to the next arrow.

How many steps of rotation are there?

[image]

---

(Drawn in *Mathematica*)

Comment: What does this figure mean?

Comment: Nice picture (what software did you use to produce it?); +1

Answer (score 0):

Write $-i$ in polar form.
$$-i=e^{\frac{3\pi i}{2}}$$
Thus
$$(-i)^{\frac{1}{4}}=e^{\frac{3\pi i}{8}+\frac{k\pi}{2}}$$
where $k \in \{ 0,1,2,3 \}$.